# What is oncontentready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the oncontentready event? 
When is it raised?
How can i use this event?
I want to convert an htc file to jquery. Please help with explaining this event.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).ready(fn)` in jquery or `$(element).load(fn)` (supports few elements)

Comment: @pavan, accept any answers which suits you. This help coming user identify right answer without reading whole thread

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom function/code call when all page elements are loaded (including images and css).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // your code will be executed after all items on page will be loaded

});
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that content ready event happens when DOM has been loaded (but not necessarily rendered as is with images that still need to be downloaded and rendered). So it happens before page load...

Comment: This answer, as stated, is incorrect - it's when the DOM has been parsed and is ready. Images could (and will) likely be loaded long after this event has fired.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery API docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> Most browsers provide similar functionality in the form of a
>   DOMContentLoaded event.

Looking at [DOMContentLoaded on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) it states (emphasis mine):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, **without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading**.

This event **does not wait** for external assets (like images, scripts, CSS, etc) to load and is fired as soon as the DOM has been parsed by the browser.

Comment: How embarrassing - the original question was edited and it showed up high in my SO feed despite the fact that it is over 6 years old :S